# putting elements before the <html> tag

Tags: html, validation

for an application I am showing emails that have been sent out, and some of them (as stored in my system) or multipart/html, so the content will normally be something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

etc..

I need to have a div at the top something like this that does not interfere with the HTML content:

```
<div id="stats"> (list subject, to, from, date, etc) </div>
```

It's an app obviously, so not publicly viewable.  It only needs to work in a few browsers, and yes, it may use jQuery in the future - so I wanted to ask the community if there are any things to consider or accommodate when putting HTML elements *ABOVE* the actual  and  tags.

Comment: One really, really shouldn't do this. It's invalid HTML, and it may show undefined behaviour.

Comment: You should never put anything outside the html tags if it is rendering `HTML`....

Answer (score 0):

Place the element immediately within the `<body>` element. Otherwise, the browser will likely do this for you. Placing it outside the `<html>` element is invalid. If you wish for the elements to be hidden, hide them with CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hidden Element</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div hidden>This is hidden.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above uses the [`hidden` attribute](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/attributes/hidden). It's presently not well supported, so you may prefer to use `display:none` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing may work most of the time, but it will lead to invalid HTML, and may cause unexpected behaviour further down the line. Even though it will probably work, I wouldn't advices it.

The better approach is, as Jonathan already says, to place the element directly inside the `body` element.

To avoid it overlapping the other content, you could force something like `margin-top: 80px` on the body.

Seeing as E-Mails are unlikely to contain anything funky like absolutely positioned elements (that would collide with your info bar), that should work for the vast majority of cases.